# UIDatePicker Default Date as 1/1/1970 comes back as 1/1/1969

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I set a default date of 1/1/1970 on a date picker. If I don't change the date, but look at datePicker.date it comes out as 1/1/1969. If I change the date, it comes out correctly. Setting the default date to any other date works fine without changing it. It just doesn't seem to like 1/1/1970.

Has anyone encountered this before? What was your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was with my format. I was using YYYY in my custom date format, but I should have been using yyyy, as the uppercase is the ISO year-week calendar.

So apparently in the ISO calendar 1/1/1970 == 1/1/1969.

Comment: Good find, you never mentioned using an NSDateFormatter in your original question you just said when you look at the date, thats why it is important to post code :) http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 3):

When you are setting the date to the default be conscious of the time zone. 1/1/1970 00:00 UTC could easily change the year to 1969 any where in the americas (west of UTC). I am not entirely sure why you would be getting 1/1 as the month and year though.

Comment: Technically the date is 1/1/1970 10:53 am according to my IB, so the offset shouldn't be a problem on the east coast. If time zone was an issue it should return 12/31/1969.

Comment: I do not see how an exact year could change without actually doing math on the date, either subtracting a year from the date component or the POSIX time itself. Have you tried other dates? post some example code of how you are setting the default date. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Other dates are 100% correct. It's just 1/1/1970 that's a problem. The default date is getting set in IB.

Comment: I just created an XCode 4 universal app with just a window, on the window I have a date picker defaulted to January 1 1970 in IB. In code i set it up to NSLog the date value when ever touches began and I always get the correct output **1970-01-01 05:00:00 +0000** without ever changing the picker. :/

Comment: Did you try getting the date without touching it? That's the case really.

Comment: Interesting...when I set my nsdateformatter date format to MM/dd/YYYY it comes back as 1/1/1969, but when it's one of the default formats it comes back correct.